# US B-2 Visa - is it Voided if I get convicted of a minor offense?

Tags: visas, usa

I was issued a B-2 US tourist visa in 2009 and it has a 10 year validity, so expiring in 2019. The visa also permits multiple entries.

I have since been involved in a minor brush with the law, resulting in a community order and a fine. Does this void my Visa? Or will it just make gaining a new one in 2019 more difficult?

I'm due to get married in the USA next year hence my question.

Answer (score 13):

You are welcome to continue using the visa until its expiration date, but remember that you will be checked at the border by a CBP officer, who will make the final determination as to whether you are admissible to the US.

That said...

In general, crimes that will make you inadmissible to the US involve "crimes of moral turpitude" (such as murder, grand theft, etc.) when sentenced to prison time, crimes involving controlled substances, along with sex trafficking, money laundering, terrorism and things like that.

If you only received a fine for whatever it was, and it was *not* regarding a controlled substance such as cannabis, then it's unlikely to affect your eligibility to enter the US.

When you apply for a new visa, you will have to disclose the new criminal conviction, and the consular officer will advise you if this makes you inadmissible to enter the US, and whether (and how) you can apply for a waiver of inadmissibility. If the crime would normally make you inadmissible, but you receive such a waiver, you can still travel to the US.

Comment: Important caveat to that "crimes of moral turpitude" provision.  It's been used to deny green cards and even deport people who have convictions for petty crimes such as shoplifting and DUI.  Given the current political climate, it's probably prudent to consider that every crime is a crime of moral turpitude that could result in denied entry or a denied visa (as has actually been the case for decades).